# Android Developer Sample BluetoothLeGatt has no scan results

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I built and ran the Android Developer sample BluetoothLeGatt on a Galaxy S9.  It runs, but never shows any results in the Scan.  Literally nothing.  BT is on, I have devices broadcasting advertising packets.  I paired one of them thinking maybe it needs that, but still nothing.

Anything come to mind?  I was hoping to see basically a huge list of devices around the office in a list of some sort.

Thanks.[image]

Comment: The UUID that is used in advertising should be the same as it is used while doing the scanning. Also, make sure you have the location permission granted before scanning.

Comment: Location is on. The app samples are installed but they dont show in the Privacy list for location, my guess is they were never provisioned for it.  I loaded Microchip's Bluetooth Data app from the Store. It scans fine. If I open BT on the device and scan, I see available devices.  Puzzling.  I tried the other demo Bluetooth Advertisements just now, and its the same thing. Empty scan results. Puzzling

Comment: Can you please provide the link of sample application that you have followed?

Comment: sure. https://github.com/android/connectivity-samples/tree/master/BluetoothLeGatt/#readme    that's the one.  But any of those connectivity-samples that scan.

Comment: Check my answer below and see if it works. you have to have location permission in manifest file and also need to change how to start foreground notification.

Comment: that's it.  Dunno how you figured that out! Amazing.  Why isnt that in their example if its so crucial I wonder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you have the following permission in AndroidManifest.xml file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE"/>
```

Check the location permission on MainActivity.java, if not then grant the Location permission.

Also, in AdvertiserService.java start the foreground notification like this:

```
String CHANNEL_ID = "44";
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_LOW)
                .setOngoing(true)
                .setAutoCancel(false)
                .setContentTitle("Ble DEMO")
                .setContentText("BLE content text")
                .setTicker("TICKER")
                .setChannelId(CHANNEL_ID)
                .setVibrate(new long[]{0L})
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
        Notification notification = builder.build();
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID, "NOTIFICATION_BLE_CHANNEL_NAME", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);
            channel.setDescription("NOTIFICATION_BLE_CHANNEL_DESC");
            channel.enableVibration(false);
            channel.setLockscreenVisibility(Notification.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC);
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
        }
        startForeground(FOREGROUND_NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);
```

Comment: Once you add the provisioning lines, you have to go into Location, App Permissions, and you will find BluetoothLeGatt on the DENIED list.  You have to allow it. After that it works.